# Force logoff when logon hour expires

Tags: windows-server-2008, active-directory, group-policy

I want to know how i can force to log off my ADDS user when their logon hour expires restricted by group policy. They are still able to log on their client PCs although their logon restricted time expires.

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't look like there is a [GPO settings specificly](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en/winserverGP/thread/a3b78bcd-3b04-480c-994e-1e066765582b) for it. What you could do is force a script to run with [Scheduled task](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc725745.aspx) at a certain time.

```
shutdown /l /f
```